# Is there a more concise way of writing "$a ? $a : $b"?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

In PHP, is there a more concise way of writing `$x ? $x : $y`? Repeating `$x` feels unnecessary, especially if it's a longer expression. It's not very important how false values are handled, as long as `$y` is returned when `$x` is undefined or null.

In Perl, I'd use `$x // $y` or `$x || $y`.

Comment: try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911235/is-there-a-better-way-of-writing-v-v-0-1-0 it is javascript but works perfectly with PHP, hope it helps

Comment: @Gerep: The only similarity between the questions seems to be the operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but only if you have PHP 5.3+ installed. You can simply miss out the middle part:

```
$x ?: $y
```

See the documentation in the manual for [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: Note that it isn't _actually_ "miss[ing] out the middle part" so much as it is the use of a different operator.

Comment: @lonesomeday: The manual has _all sorts_ of confusing and misleading phrasing. For example the continual use of the term "ternary operator" on the page about conditional operators, propagating a horrid myth. Fortunately, PHP devs accept manual bug reports and usually act on them swiftly; I've submitted more than a few myself that have been promptly adopted.

Comment: Calling this a "ternary operator" is _even worse_ than doing so for `a?b:c`, not least because it's a _binary_ operator.

Comment: It's arguably a ternary operator with the second argument implicit. Clearly you have strong opinions on the matter.

Comment: By that logic, every unary operator is _actually_ a ternary operator with two implicit dummy operands. You'll get no traction with that.