# Better way of PHP if shorthand

Tags: php

I was wondering whether there's a better way of writing this? I am aware that the answer could be no.

```
$variable = aMethodToGetSomeValue();

$result = ($variable) ? $variable : null/false/0;
```

Basically, I want to set the result to `$variable` if `$variable` is not false, else return as defined.

The above code works, the question is just whether there's a better way of writing the shorthand? Since the use case for me is such that the `$variable` is a query to the database.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911235/is-there-a-better-way-of-writing-v-v-0-1-0) but not really what I'm asking for I believe..?

Comment: Look up shorthand ternary if PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up shorthand ternary if PHP >= 5.3

Example:

```
<?php
$e = "asdf";
$e = ($e) ?: "foo";

var_dump($e); // string(4) "asdf" 
?>
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know this one! :)