# how to print 1 when user enters 0 in input field without using any condition or loop in java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

yesterday i went to an interview i was asked a question which is below

Create an **input field** and **button** user should enter only **0 or 1** when the user enters 0 the output should be 1. when the user enters 1 the output should be 0. Write the logic of minimum 5 possible way of the output?

**Note:**

We should not use any if,for,while,do while,if else,switch,.. (no condition and loops) should be used.

It should be done in java script and minimum 5 possible way to print the out .

I don't know whether it is possible or not for 5 times. if any one knows please help me

Comment: Most likely they mean to use the truthy/falsy properties of JavaScript. Look for the solution in that direction.

Comment: Beside that you should at least show something you have tried and/or some thoughts about it. `user **should** enter only` can the user enter something else then `0` or`1`, if so what should be the output for an input that is not `0` or `1`. `Write the logic of minimum 5 possible way of the output` what does this mean? What are the _different way of output_ .

Comment: do you have to take restrictions about what user type or we know that always he'll type what expected?

Comment: @t.niese he probably means to find 5 different solutions.

Comment: @t.niese no the user should enter only 0 and 1. we should print the same output with minimum of diffrent ways but the output should be same when user enters 0 and click the button the output should be 1. like that

Comment: @meskobalazs actully i did not get anything in my mind so i left that question.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas no user should type only 0 or 1

Comment: Here are many different ways how you could do it: [Is there a better way of writing v = (v == 0 ? 1 : 0);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911235/is-there-a-better-way-of-writing-v-v-0-1-0) including array, bitwise, modulo, comparison, ....

Comment: @WaKai so you only read the title of the question, without taking a look at the answers?

Comment: @t.niese thanks may be that can help me

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

```
console.log(~ document.getElementById('input_field').value + 2 );
```

~ Inverts the bits, so you will get `-2` for the input 1 and `-1` for the input 0. Then just add 2 to get your result.

Edit #2:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('input_field').value ^ 1);
```

Using the XOR (^) Operator.

Edit #3:

Plain simple, just subtract the input from 1:

```
console.log(1 - document.getElementById('input_field').value);
```