# Correct way to toggle between two string values with ternary expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am trying to have a string that toggle between two values. I have declared as ternary

```
public position: string = (this.position == "positionOne" ? "positionOne" : "positionTwo");
```

What I would like to have a function for directly toggle from "positionOne" to "positionTwo" (value of the string). Something like `

```
togglePosition = function() 
     {this.position = !this.position}
```

and then it takes the opposite string as value. Or I need to do the complete evaluation also if declared as ternary? and then see `if (position = "positionOne")`... do whatever.. or `else` the upside down.
 You know what I mean? :) What solution you suggest to me?

Thanks a lot from now

Comment: do you really mean javascript? or java? if javascript, why do you use a typed variable?

Comment: @NinaScholz it's typescript

Comment: Your ternary operation is fine, except that you should swap the final two values, otherwise you don't change anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an object and the keys as the wanted value.

```js
function toggle(v) {
    return { positionOne: 'positionTwo', positionTwo: 'positionOne' }[v];
}
 
var position = 'positionOne';
console.log(position);
position = toggle(position);
console.log(position);
position = toggle(position);
console.log(position);
```

Comment: You hit the nail, great. It is what I was looking for. So usefull. With your permise I pick this snippet with me.

Comment: you can use it. you may have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31028514/1447675) for a extended use of the same style.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you could use this (in cases where the values do not match "half-way"):

```js
function toggle(pos) {
    return 'positionOnepositionTwo'.replace(pos, '');
}

pos = 'positionOne';
console.log(pos = toggle(pos));
console.log(pos = toggle(pos));
console.log(pos = toggle(pos));
```

#### Alternative with `find`

```js
function toggle(pos) {
    return ['positionOne','positionTwo'].find(x => x !== pos);
}

pos = 'positionOne';
console.log(pos = toggle(pos));
console.log(pos = toggle(pos));
console.log(pos = toggle(pos));
```

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions.

Comment: You seem a little agitated. When I say you are jumping to conclusions, I refer to *"poaching one other person's solution"*. Although I understand you may interpret it that way, I posted this solution without being aware that you were having the same idea. It is not unusual that different people come up with the same idea at about the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you could use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to do the same thing Nina mentioned:

```js
var log = console.log;
function toggle(v) {
   return ['positionOne','positionTwo'].find(s=>s!=v);
}
 
var position = 'positionOne';
log( position );

position = toggle(position);
log( position );

position = toggle(position);
log( position );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the 'correct way' will depend on the person and project. For simple problems i prefer the ternary way or the answer by @Nina Scholz.

You can also use ES6 destructuring:

```
({ [position]: position } = { positionOne: "positionTwo", positionTwo: "positionOne" });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var position = "positionOne";

    function myFunction() {
      ({
        [position]: position
      } = {
        positionOne: "positionTwo",
        positionTwo: "positionOne"
      });
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = position;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

An interesting alternative using destructuring, although probably not the best for this use case, can be obtained by toggling the values of two variables:

```
var positionA = "positionOne";
var positionB = "positionTwo";
[positionA, positionB] = [positionB, positionA];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var positionA = "positionOne";
    var positionB = "positionTwo";

    function myFunction() {
      [positionA, positionB] = [positionB, positionA];
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = positionA;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Or just use an object:

```
var position = {a: 'positionOne', b: 'positionTwo'};    
[position.a, position.b] = [position.b, position.a];
```

The advantage of this solution is that enable one to change between multiple values and not just two (However for this you should probably use [the solution mentioned earlier in its extensive form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028514/3658510)).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var positionA = "positionOne";
    var positionB = "positionTwo";
    var positionC = "positionThree";
    var positionD = "positionFour";

    function myFunction() {
      [positionA, positionB, positionC, positionD] = [positionB, positionC, positionD, positionA];
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = positionA;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense to store the state of which string to display in a boolean variable, which you can easily toggle, then write a method that returns the appropriate string based on the boolean variable.

Comment: Usefull comment with yours and other answers I have now it much more clear. Thank you.