# How can I implement logics without if else, switch or a built-in function in javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

Suppose we have function, which returns 3 when passing 5 to it and return 5 when passing 3 to it. I know it is very easy  with if else and switch.

for example

```
function countReturn(number){
  if(number === 3){
  return 5
 }

  if(number === 5){
  return 3
 }
```

}

But how can I implement the same logic without if else, switch or any built-in function?

Comment: `return {3:5,5:3}[number]`?

Comment: You can use the Ternary operator. `return number === 3 ? 5 : 3`

Comment: What is actually the goal here? What should `countReturn(1)` or `countReturn(12)` produce?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911235/is-there-a-better-way-of-writing-v-v-0-1-0/31028514#31028514).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the return values in an array:

```
function countReturn(n) {
  let a = [,,,5,,3];
  return a[n];
}
```

That will return `undefined` for other inputs, just like your original code.

Comment: Marking your answer. Although its not valid to provide the empty elements but it does work the logic.

Comment: @WahasAliMughal it is valid to have empty elements in an array literal.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the sum (3 + 5) and return the delta of the actual number.

```js
function threeOrFive(value) {
    return 8 - value;
}

console.log(threeOrFive(3)); // 5
console.log(threeOrFive(5)); // 3
```

Comment: `threeOrFive(1)` seems to return `7`, rather than OP's function which would return `undefined` in that case. Not sure what OP actually wants to happen with non-3 and non-5 values, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can so it with ternary like this

```
return number === 3 ? 5 : (number === 5 ? 3 : 0);
```

Or you can do it with object

```
const obj = {
  "5": 3,
  "3": 5
};
return obj[number];
```

Comment: I'm not sure a conditional expression counts as something different to an `if`.

Comment: @VLAZ I add a methode with object. In case ternary aren't allowed

Comment: Ternary is a conditional statement. So can't mark your answer.

Comment: @WahasAliMughal I understand, just consider the object methode for your futur developement

Answer (score 0):

We can return the xored value between 5 and 3:

```js
return number ^ 6
```

Implementing the same logic, it would return `3` when given `5` and vice versa