# which one is faster objects or if statments?

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, data-structures

I am making chess engine as a project I noticed that I had to use a lot of if statments because of that code was hard to read I came up with this solution for example when changing turns instead of writing

```
if(turn=="white"){
    turn="black"
}else{
    turn="white"
}
```

I did this

```
const switchTurns={
   "white":"black",
   "black":"white"   
}
turn=switchTurns[turn]
```

it looks like I am making my job harder with this objects but it helped a lot when I had to check way more things to get value like pisce, pisce index,is it middlegame or not and change tham based on other stuff I am 17year old I learned on my own and I don't know exactly how everything works behind programming languages I am wondering does this method makes program slower or it is same? also is this good practice or not and why? thanks in advance

Comment: You need something called a profiler. That's the only way to know.

Comment: There is little performance differences really. What is most important to you right now is code visibility. I will prefer second method obviously since it's less codes (e.g. 10 objects vs 10 if-else statements)

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: maybe a look worth: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6911235/1447675

Comment: it's faster and easier to use a boolean `isWhiteTurn` and switch turns like `isWhiteTurn = !isWhiteTurn`